# Adding a link here on the trilogy SharePoint tag wikis: advisable?

Tags: discussion, migration

It crossed my mind as another way to bring people across:

"For SharePoint-specific questions, please see the [SharePoint Stack Exchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) site."

Or suchlike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, that sounds like a good use of the Tag Wikis. Nice idea.

Go ahead and add the text and link.

*Note that I edited your original quote with the current name and URL of the site.*

Comment: I'll get editing

Comment: ~12 tag wikis add/edited (sharepoint20* on 3 sites), and only 4 accusations of being a robot. I'm now also slightly curious as to the meaning of "aseasous".